# C# - Transfering a control from a thread to another one

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

The more a window is filled with content, the more it will take to load completely, and the user will only be able to use any of the controls when it have already finished.

So I imagined the following:

Making a window empty of controls and create them on another thread, like BackgroundWorker.
Then, the controls would be added to the main grid gradually, so the user could use the first controls without having to wait the rest to be created.

To try to bring it to reality, I've already tried to use some techniques. The last one was trying to use Invoke, which, actually, I don't know neither how that works nor how to use.

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CreateControls));
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
    }

private void CreateControls()
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Width = 90;
        btn.Height = 30;
        btn.Background = Brushes.Black;
        btn.Foreground = Brushes.White;
        btn.Content = "Click me";

        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                MainGD.Children.Add(btn);
            }));
        });
    }
```

At `MainGD.Children.Add(btn);` I receive:
**The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.**

In my research, I found the method of putting the button creation inside the Invoke, like this:

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Width = 90;
            btn.Height = 30;
            btn.Background = Brushes.Black;
            btn.Foreground = Brushes.White;
            btn.Content = "Click me";

            MainGD.Children.Add(btn);
        }));
    });
```

But I don't want to create the control in the main thread.
Could anyone help me with this?
Is that possible at all?

---

The point is: Is it possible to create a GUI control inside another thread and transfer it to the GUI thread? That's what I was trying to do.

Comment: UI work must always be done on the UI thread, if you aren't asking how to avoid that (which you can't) what exactly are you asking?

Comment: How long is it actually taking for this form to load?  How many controls does it have on it?  Does loading it depend on retrieving data from a data source?

Comment: If it takes a long enough time for your user to actually perceive the time it takes to construct your form, something is probably wrong with it.  Either it's trying to do *way* more than it should, or you're computing some non-UI work in there and that non-UI work is what should be done in another thread.  That, or you're worrying over something that's not a problem, and your form loads fast enough already.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Actually, I don't have any form. That was an idea to a future Project.

Comment: Then this is almost certainly premature optimization. Parallelizing a form load is going to be your last resort after you've exhausted all other possibilities, including simplifying your form.

Comment: Please delete all your code immediately. **Do not create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for**. If you're having problems with a particular UI, please post the relevant XAML for that UI and we can help you troubleshoot. If you're doing this just as an experiment, forget it. **Premature optimization is the root of all evil** And XAML based-technologies have built-in means to improve performance, such as UI Virtualization. You don't need any of what you're doing here, which can't be done anyways because UI elements can only be manipulated in the UI Thread

Comment: So, it isn't possible to do what I wanted to do. Thank you for the answers!
I just wanted to have the application opened as fast as when it is just a blank window, independently of how elaborated the window was, you know?

Answer (score 1):

Nice idea, but that won't work I'm afraid. User interface code must go on the GUI thread.

BackgroundWorkers and threads are for doing *work* and the GUI thread is for doing user interface. "Work" is things like number-crunching or database lookup: things which will eventually send their *results* to the GUI thread for display.

If your form takes too long to load purely from adding controls to it then there's too many controls, probably - see if you can redesign it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like async/await may be of use here.    I worked on a project where our Window UI consisted of some menu items on the top, a region of custom controls in the middle, and some action buttons (like Ok, Cancel) on the bottom.  The menu items and action buttons are created when the Window is created.  However, the controls in the middle region were generated using asynchronous calls.

We used an ObservableCollection as the data source for an ItemsControl in the middle region.  Then, in the Window.ContentRendered event (so after the window has been drawn) we "awaited" a method that built the custom controls.

Here's a snippet of MyWindow code-behind:

```
public partial class MyWindow : Window
{
    /* Window c'tor, other methods/props ommited */

    // Load our custom controls asynchronously after the window is rendered
    private async void MyWindow_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // kick off the asynchronous call to create a custom controls
        await CreateCustomControls();
    }

    // Asynchronously adds MyCustomControls to the ObservableCollection 
    // (we actually used a separate static class that contained our definitions
    // and created the controls) 
    private async Task CreateCustomControls()
    {
        // the def describes what you want to build and is not detailed here
        foreach (var controlDef in MyCustomControlDefinitions)
        {
            // create a control based on the definition
            var newControl = await CreateMyCustomControl(controlDef);

            // Don't add the control until it is completely built
            MyCustomControls.Add(newControl);
        }
    }

    //The (bindable) collection of custom controls
    public ObservableCollection<MyCustomControl> MyCustomControls
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<MyCustomControl>)GetValue(MyCustomControlsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyCustomControlsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCustomControlsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MyCustomControls", typeof(ObservableCollection<MyCustomControl>),
        typeof(MyWindow), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<MyCustomControl>()));

}
```

Here's a snippet of the MyWindow XAML:

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <!-- Scrollable Panel for MyCustomControls -->
        <ScrollViewer>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCustomControls}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Its important to note that it only provides a "perceived" performance increase.  All we did was allow the window to be somewhat useful while we creating the rest of the controls.  So users could interact with the top and bottom controls immediately (when the window is shown) and once the custom controls were added to the ObservableCollection, the user could interact with them as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your code makes use of things I've never used before (I'm a beginner (ok, that's already obvious)). But it sounds like that's what I need. I'm planning to make a personal browser that would load quickly, with just the adress bar being ready for immediate use while the rest is created and loaded.

Comment: await/async are relatively new to .NET.  Checkout this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx#BKMK_AsyncandAwait) article.

Comment: Could you tell me what it is, exactly, those custom controls you mention in your answer? Are they buttons, labels, etc or literally, custom controls (made by you for the project)? And `CreateMyCustomControl()` was a method of that class you said?

Comment: And if it isn't too much.. Could you explain how that class work? I'm with some difficulties to understand how the whole thing works and I think your answer is the closest I would have of what I need.

Comment: The custom controls were just a set of normal controls like `TextBlock`, `ComboBox`, `Checkbox`, etc that were grouped together by some container (`WrapPanel` or StackPanel`) with some styling. Each control was decorated with an [Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454.aspx) like "Group1".  Our static class took the definition (a list of Attributes) and called a Factory to create control(s) using [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z919e8tw.aspx) (we'd search the Assembly for Types that were decorated with specific custom Attribute that was passed in).

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! I'll study what you did. That's all new to me.